# Issue when migrating CodedUI test from VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am having some serious issue when migrating Coded UI test from VS2010 to VS2012. The issue is related to assembly reference. I try to reference the new 11.0 version CodedUI assemblies, but the system keeps looking for the old 10.0 version when VS2012 tries to find all the cases and list in the Test Viewer. Such as:

> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I found this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/hh506981(v=vs.110).aspx

It mentions some issue related to assemlby reference. But I don't understand the following quotation:

> In Visual Studio 2010, references were added inside a ‘Choose’
>   statement in the csproj file. In Visual Studio 2012, we are using
>   **a Feedback targets file** to include Coded UI Test Assembly references.

What is **a Feedback targets file**??

Answer (score 0):

I've covered your problem with [the answer in this blog post](http://www.vlaquest.com/2012/12/migrating-coded-ui-tests-to-vs-2012-small-issue-with-project-dependencies/).

You need to open your proj file and check for the logic that has been added to reference properly the version 11.0.0.0 of the testing tools assemblies.

I presume the feedback targets file is the imported msbuild file in the VS 2012 folder for msbuild targets. It is an implementation detail, all you need is to focus in upgrading your project file according to what the "repair" wizard is supposed to do, I give precise steps in my post.
Regards and good luck (if I'm not too late)